# Run handler on opengl thread

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to recreate a scene of GL_POINTS each second and I tried to use a handler for this:

```
 private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createRandomGridPoints();
            mPoint = new Point(pointCoords,colorCoords);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
```

I use `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);` inside the onSufraceCreated method. 
The points get created, but I get nothing on the screen and I have this error in the logcat: `call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)`.

I think the problem might be that the runnable is not running on the opengl thread. Is it possible to solve this?

Points class:

```
public class Point {
    private  int mProgram, mPositionHandle, mColorHandle, mMVPMatrixHandle;
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer,colorBuffer;
    private static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    private static final int COORDS_PER_COLOR = 4;
    private  int vertexCount,colorCount;


    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                    "attribute mediump vec4 vColor;" +
                    "varying mediump vec4 vaColor;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  vaColor = vColor;" +
                    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                    "   gl_PointSize = 100.0;" +
                    "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
                    "varying mediump vec4 vaColor;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = vaColor;" +
                    "}";


    private static int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;
    private final int colorStride = COORDS_PER_COLOR * 4;


    public Point(float pointCoords[],float colorCoords[]){
        this.vertexCount = pointCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
        this.colorCount = colorCoords.length / COORDS_PER_COLOR;

        FloatBuffer[] buffers = getBuffers(pointCoords,colorCoords);



        vertexBuffer = buffers[0];
        colorBuffer = buffers[1];


        int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                fragmentShaderCode);

        // create empty OpenGL ES Program
        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);

        // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);

        // creates OpenGL ES program executables
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);


        // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");


        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram,"vColor");

        // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    }

    public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the point coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                vertexStride, vertexBuffer);



        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);
        // Set color for drawing the triangle
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, COORDS_PER_COLOR, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                colorStride, colorBuffer);


        //TRANSLATION
        float[] transMatrix = new float[16];

        Matrix.setIdentityM(transMatrix,0);
        Matrix.translateM(transMatrix,0,0.5f,0,0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(transMatrix,0,mvpMatrix,0,transMatrix,0);


        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }

    /**
     * Change content of buffer
     */
    public void changeBufferData(float[] newBufferInfo) {
//        GLES20.glBufferSubData(?,0,newBufferInfo.length*4,vertexBuffer);
    }

    private FloatBuffer[] getBuffers(float pointCoords[],float colorCoords[]){
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pointCoords.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(pointCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer cbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colorCoords.length * 4);
        cbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer colorBuffer = cbb.asFloatBuffer();
        colorBuffer.put(colorCoords);
        colorBuffer.position(0);

        return new FloatBuffer[]{vertexBuffer,colorBuffer};
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The openGL context is designed to use multithreading. When doing something with openGL on a separate thread you should have another context on that thread and set it as current. That means a context must be set on every of the threads you want to use openGL. It is possible to use the same context on multiple threads but unless you are sure what you are doing I do not suggest you to do that; since you are drawing it on the screen that is most definitely not the case to use the same context.

Now to share the resources between contexts you will need to have a shared context which should be one of the context constructors. You need to insert the main context into it. This is used when you need to load large data in background such as textures.

But your case is a bit specific. The data you create are not bound to openGL so there is no reason to set the context on this thread nor to create a new context. You should somehow go back to your main openGL thread and draw the points.

So the easiest solution is to call the draw method from your thread on the main thread. But there are multiple ways on achieving your goal depending on your situation:

1. If the scene is designed to be redrawn on demand (This means it will not execute few times per second but only when you call a method such as `redraw`): You need to explicitly call this method on the thread that is designed to present the content on the screen (your main openGL thread). You may pass the points into the draw method `drawPoints(points)` or assign it to the class responsible for the drawing `mainEngine.points = points; mainEngine.redraw();`
2. If the scene keeps redrawing itself constantly then the redraw is already on your main thread. In this case the solution is pretty simple. The engine should have the logic to draw points so in your `onDraw` method there should be some logic such as `foreach (point in this.points) drawPoint(point)` then all you need to do is set the new points once they are complete, threads will not have an impact `mainEngine.points = points` should do.
3. If the scene is not thread depended and you are doing some data processing you can then move the logic throughout the threads. This is in no way appropriate for on screen drawing but is more for drawing to a FBO. In this case you want the forward the context whenever you swat the thread and set the context as current on the new thread while removing the context as current from the previous thread.

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer. I'm in the second case, but I already have a draw method that does this in my Point class `GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);`. I assume that the surfaceView is no longer available for it to draw the points.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "no longer available". Adding some more code of your system might help identifying the problem. Also try to debug it with some breakpoints after the points are created and assigned and then in the draw method to compare the data.

Comment: I've been trying to debug it, but no luck so far. I've updated with the point class. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I see. Well you made this all upside down. The constructor for the Point should only create the CPU buffers and have a method to draw which can then execute the openGL commands.  You still need to assign the point to your surface view so surfaceView.point = Point(...). Then on surface draw method you call this.point.draw().

Comment: I had it the normal way( only the CPU buffers), but I've been playing around with it, trying to solve the issue and this was the latest thing that I had. I'll try to do that assigning thing that you talk about. Thank you.

Comment: I've added a point object in my surface view, and now in the handler i just set that point to a new one and in the `onDrawFrame` method I'm using `myGLSurfaceView.getPoint().draw(mMVPMatrix);`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: ALL the openGL calls must be called on the main thread in your case.